# conda-build: How to keep the test environment?

Tags: conda

According to [documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/concepts/recipe.html#conda-build-process) on conda-build process, the testing step involves

> Once a package is built, conda-build will test it. To do this, it
> **creates another environment** and installs the conda package. The form
> of this prefix is:
>
> `<path to conda>/conda-bld/<package name + string>/_test_env_placeholder…`

## Is there a way to keep this test environment around, after the conda-build process finishes?

Currently, it seems that Conda automatically deletes this environment after building the package.

My use case:

- After building the package, I need to create a Conda environment that contains just that one package (and all its dependencies).
- In fact, I'm trying to create the very environment that the testing step had just created
- Therefore, I am hoping to keep that test environment around and simply clone/reuse it

Answer (score 0):

You can try `conda build --dirty` or use `conda debug`.

If the build succeeds, you should also be able to install your package by doing `conda install --use-local <package name>`.

References:

- https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/commands/conda-build.html?highlight=dirty#conda-build
- https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/recipes/debugging.html